# jQuery Keyup Count TextLength for SMS

Tags: jquery, sms, keyup

I'm creating an sms sender. And i have a textbox. Now i'm using jQuery Keyup event for count text length.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sms">SMS</label>
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="sms" name="sms"></textarea>
        <span class="pull-right" id="smslength">0</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">SMS Gönder</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#sms').keyup(function(){
        sms = $(this).val();
        $('#smslength').html(sms.length);
    })
</script>
```

But for special characters SMS counts 2 (like Ş , ş , Ğ , ğ , ç , ı , İ)

I want to count as two character when i type the characters above. Is there any function for jQuery for multi-byte characters ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just include an if block that checks the pressed key's character code (and if it is one of the mentioned ones)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var codes = ["Ş", "ş", "Ğ", "ğ", "ç", "ı", "İ"];
    $('#sms').keyup(function(e){
     if($.inArray(e.charCode, codes)){
         //double value
    }else{    
         //normal value
    }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: in here ($.inArray(e.charCode, codes) codes is correct or it should be cars ?

Comment: should be cars or the name you give to your array of codes (sorry typo)

Answer (score 0):

This is my html code

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sms">SMS</label>
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="sms" name="sms" maxlength="745"></textarea>
        <span class="pull-right"><span id="smslength">0</span> / <span id="maxsmslength">745</span> [SMS Adeti: <span id="smscount">0</span>]</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">SMS Gönder</button>
</form>
```

This is my jQuery Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#sms').keyup(function(){
        doubleChars = ["Ş", "ş", "Ğ", "ğ", "ç", "ı", "İ"];

        sms = $(this).val();
        textlength = sms.length;

        smslength = 0;

    if(textlength > 0){
            for(i=0; i < textlength; i++){
                if($.inArray(sms.charAt(i), doubleChars) !== -1){
                    //double value
                    smslength += 2;
                }else{    
                    //normal value
                    smslength++
                }
            }
        }

        $('#smslength').html(smslength);

        if(smslength == 0){
            smscount = 0;
        } else if(smslength > 0 && smslength <= 155){
            smscount = 1;
        } else if(smslength > 155 && smslength <= 298){
            smscount = 2;
        } else if(smslength > 298 && smslength <= 447){
            smscount = 3;
        } else if(smslength > 447 && smslength <= 596){
            smscount = 4;
        } else if(smslength > 596 && smslength <= 745){
            smscount = 5;
        }

        $('#smscount').html(smscount);
    })
```